# Kerberos Pass through authentication with Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, kerberos

I'm wondering if someone can please point me to some documentation that covers this. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you even look at the Tomcat documentation?

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html

Comment: Yes - I use krb authentication but i don't see anything around pass through krb auth

Comment: @user1181862, you are unwilling to invest some time to investigate. Mark provided your enough information for a good start. The SPNEGO authenticator will extract the delegated credential if there is one.